# SNMP OIDs Documentation

Tags: snmp

I am looking for documentation on SNMP IODs return values. For example, the MIB IBM-SYSTEM-HEALTH-MIB  1.3.6.1.4.1.2.6.159.1.1.30 , it provides information on temperature, voltage, and fan status.

1.3.6.1.4.1.2.6.159.1.1.30.3.1.2 provides information on Current State. However, I am not sure what the return values 0 and 3 mean.

Does anyone know where I can find any documentation on these return values for OIDs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Like lextm-MSFT said, you can find the answer in your vendor's MIB file.  If you can't find them on your vendor's support website, Bytesphere (http://www.oidview.com/mibs/vendors.html) is an excellent resource for enterprise MIBs.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the MIB document at hand and check out description section for each objects. Besides, consult IBM support team to see if they have other official documents on that.